# map empty json array to object

Tags: json, angular, angular2-services

I have an api call that returns a json message. One of the variables in the message is an object array, sometimes that array is empty but the data in that array is needed so that it can be 2-way data-bound to angular material elements in the HTML Code. I need a work around for when that object array is empty, the DOM elements don't error out because the array is undefined. It should just leave those angular material elements blank.
(I would like to do this without using nfIf on the elements since they should still be displayed.)

The way the code is currently set up the name variable is not 2-way data bound to the variable because it does not get updated.

I have already attempted using elvis operators but those do not work with [(ngModel)]. I can one way bind with [ngModel]="array?.value" but not update. Adding (ngModelChange) = "datasource?.value? = $event" , is not working because the '?' is an unexpected token.
Is there anything I can do on the JSON mapping side?

### service.ts

```
GetData(identificationNum: string): Observable<DATA_OBJECT>{
    return this.http.get<DATA_OBJECT>(this.service.apiAddress + 'api/GetData/' + identificationNum)
    .pipe(
        map(
            jsonObj => Object.assign(new DATA_OBJECT(), jsonObj)
        )
    );
}
```

datastructuresmodels.ts

```
export class DATA_OBJECT
    {
        public header: Object ;
        public identificationNum: string  ;
        public infoArray: Array<Info> ;

    }

export class Info
    {
        public name: string;
        public address: string  ;
        public gender: string ;
    }
```

### component.ts

```
data: DATA_OBJECT;
dataSource: Info[];

ngOnInit() {
this.service.GetStowData(this.number).subscribe(
        (data: DATA_OBJECT) => (this.data = data),
        error => console.log(error),
        () => {
          this.dataSource = this.data.infoArray;
        }
      );
}
```

### component.html

```
<div class="col">
                <p class="subheading">Name: </p>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Name" 
                                  [ngModel]="datasource?.name">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
```

### JSON Example of problem:

```
{     "header": {         "messageCode": 00,         "status": 0,},     "identificationNum": 123, "infoArray": [] }
```

### JSON Example Populated (functions as desired because the info is there):

```
{     "header": {         "messageCode": 00,         "status": 0,},     "identificationNum": 123, "infoArray": [{"name":"string"}, {"address":"string"}, {"gender":"string"}] }
```

The expected results are empty angular material elements even when the api responds with the empty array.

Comment: You r not twoway data binding by using [ngModel] this is Input declaration, use [(ngModel)] instead and leave out ngmodelchange. Usually u would do ngif and present the User a message so he knows whats going on. Regards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, [(ngModel)] is what I originally used, I'm having trouble using it because when that last object array is empty it can not bind to it. Like in my JSON problem example, using [(ngModel)] = "infoArrray.name" does not work because then the infoArray becomes undefined. I was able to get it to bind one way with elvis operators but need to either know how to bind on update or format the JSON message to have "infoArray": [{"name":""}, {"address":""}, {"gender":""}]  instead of having all of it's variables missing.